# How to slow down cassandra to expose eventual consistency issues

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views

I have cassandra with table and materialized views. The materialized views are eventually consistent with the table and dev has to be extra careful implementing algorithms against cassandra of not hitting issues like just added item seems to not be there etc.

What I would like is to be able to create test environment where the eventual consistency of the materialized views is on purpose really high - say 5/10ms. This way I will be at easy that if my integration tests do not hit issues they are not there. Right now my integration tests running against very small cluster that seems to do all this very fast, and I have some issues discovered only after hours of ingestion against almost production size cluster which is very expensive.

My question is: How I can slow down cassandra materialized view syncs with the table.

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view you are actually trying to solve consistency issues with the wrong concepts.

I mean, if you rely on strong consistency you shouldn't use materialised views because there is only eventual consistency with MV.